# Erro ao tentar realizar um cadastro em C#

Tags: c#, login

Estou criando um programa e preciso que o usuário faça o cadastro para logar no mesmo. Ao rodar o programa, quando tento realizar um cadastro esse erro aparece no Visual Studio:
"The model backing the 'Banco' context has changed since the database was created."
Este erro aponta esta parte do código na primeira linha (Usuario usuario ...):

```
public bool Login(String login, String senha)
    {
        Usuario usuario = this.banco.Usuarios.Where(user => user.Email.Equals(login) && user.Senha.Equals(senha)).FirstOrDefault();

        Gerenciador.usuarioLogado = usuario;

        return (usuario != null);
    }
```

Aqui o início do código:

```
public class Gerenciador
{

    public static Usuario usuarioLogado;

    private Banco banco = new Banco();
 (...)
```

Por favor, me ajudem. Preciso entregar este programa esta semana e não consigo nem logar no programa :x

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar na sua classe que representa o contexto da aplicação de banco de dados esse trecho de código:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     Database.SetInitializer<NomeDoSeuContexto>(null);
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, mas agora mudou para o erro "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException:
'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.' " 
Continuou apontado para o mesmo trecho... :s

Comment: Seu _schema_ do banco mudou desde a última vez que conseguiu fazer login? Tanto no lado C# (EF Code First) quanto no SQL Server? Se sim, você tem que sincronizar a mudança na parte que ainda não foi mudada.

Comment: Marcelo, não tenho certeza pois tenho um outro colega modificando também. 
Sabes explicar como seria essa sincronização?

Comment: Se o SQL Server ganhou/perdeu tabelas ou colunas, isso deve se refletir no Code First e vice-versa. Essa é a sincronização.

Comment: Entendi. Vou procurar por isto